# Ordered streams of pairs - Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to order streams of pairs according to the weight of the pairs - the sum of the two numbers in the pair.  (I'm not excluding duplicates.)  My code doesn't seem to be working

```
(define (merge-weighted s1 s2 weight)
  (let ((h1 (stream-car s1))
        (h2 (stream-car s2)))
    (if ((weight h1) < (weight h2))
        (cons-stream h1 (merge-weighted (stream-cdr s1) s2 weight))
        (cons-stream h2 (merge-weighted new1 (stream-cdr s2) weight)))))
```

when calling merge-weighted on a stream of integers (s1) with another stream of integers (s2) and using the following weight1:

```
(define (weight1 pair)
  (+ (car pair) (cdr pair)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it fixes a problem with a misplaced `<` and adds a couple of base cases for handling empty streams:

```
(define (merge-weighted s1 s2 weight)
  (cond ((stream-null? s1) s2)
        ((stream-null? s2) s1)
        (else
         (let ((h1 (stream-car s1))
               (h2 (stream-car s2)))
           (if (< (weight h1) (weight h2))
               (cons-stream h1 (merge-weighted (stream-cdr s1) s2 weight))
               (cons-stream h2 (merge-weighted s1 (stream-cdr s2) weight)))))))
```

To be sure, you should post as part of the question an example with the expected output for a given input.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (merge-weighted s1 s2 weight)
(let ((h1 (stream-car s1))
    (h2 (stream-car s2)))
(cond
((null? s1) s2)
((null? s2) s1)
((< (weight h1) (weight h2))
        (cons-stream h1 (merge-weighted (stream-cdr s1) s2 weight)))
(else
      (cons-stream h2 (merge-weighted s1 (stream-cdr s2) weight)))))
```

Try this one. The termination conditions was the problem i think.